# PHP- if and else statements not displaying correct output

Tags: php, html, if-statement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <title>Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Rock Paper Scissors Game</h1>
```

(2nd Page) this is a rock paper scissors game involving images...the images do show up after the user inputs (rock, scissors or paper) but usually itll be like (output= image of rock vs paper and then it'll say you win! instead of you lose! or when its a draw nothing shows up)

```
        $playerthrows = $_POST['playerthrows'];
        $Choosefrom= array('rock', 'paper', 'scissors');
        $Choice= rand(0,2);
        $Computer=$Choosefrom[$Choice];


if($playerthrows == 'rock')
    {
    echo '<img src="rock1.png" alt="rock" />';
    }

    if($playerthrows == 'paper')
    {
    echo '<img src="paper1.png" alt="paper" />';
    }

    if($playerthrows == 'scissors')
    {
    echo '<img src="scissors1.png" alt="scissors" />';
    }

    if($Computer == 0)
    {
        echo '<img src="paper2.png" alt="paper" />'; 
    }
    if($Computer == 1)
    {
    echo '<img src="scissors2.png" alt="scissors" />'; 
    }

    if($Computer == 2)
    {
    echo '<img src="rock2.png" alt="rock" />'; 
    }
```

Did i mess up with the if statements?

```
    if ($playerthrows == $Computer)
    {
    echo'<br />';
    echo 'Draw.';
    }
    else if($playerthrows == 'rock' && $Computer == 1 )
    {
    echo'<br />';
    echo 'You Win!';
    }
    else if($playerthrows == 'rock' && $Computer == 0 )
    {
    echo'<br />';   
    echo  'You Lose!';
    }
    else if($playerthrows == 'scissors' && $Computer == 2 )
    {
    echo'<br />';   
    echo  'You Lose!';
    }
    else if($playerthrows == 'scissors' && $Computer == 0 )
    {
    echo'<br />';   
    echo 'You Win!';
    }
    else if($playerthrows == 'paper' && $Computer == 2 )
    {
    echo'<br />';   
    echo 'You Win!';
    }
    else if($playerthrows == 'paper' && $Computer == 1 )
    {
    echo'<br />';   
    echo 'You Lose!';
    }



?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump` the variables`$playerthrows` and `$Computer`?  Are they what you expect them to be?

Comment: where's the form for this? Edit; Oh, I see you haven't responded to @David 's comment, so I'll just mosey along too then.

Comment: i apologize, my bad...yeah the variables are what i expect them to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your array `$Choosefrom` you declared it as `array('rock', 'paper', 'scissors')`

But in your conditions, it's being called as `array('paper', 'scissors', 'rock')` which makes the results wrong

It should be

```
if($Computer == 0)
{
    echo '<img src="rock2.png" alt="rock" />'; 
}
if($Computer == 1)
{
    echo '<img src="paper2.png" alt="paper" />'; 
}

if($Computer == 2)
{
    echo '<img src="scissors2.png" alt="scissors" />'; 
}
```

Also, you should put the word in the if-else conditions for $Computer, not their index numbers

e.g.
`else if($playerthrows == 'rock' && $Computer == 'paper' )`

Comment: thank you, the problem of the text not appearing has vanished but it still doesnt respond with the correct statement

Comment: Can you give a sample case where the statements display incorrectly? :)

Comment: sorry but what do you mean,

Comment: Also please ensure the right values for `$Computer`. `[0] => 'rock'`, `[1] => 'paper'`, `[2] => 'scissors'`

Comment: What did you input and what does the computer returns and what's the result. Something like that

Comment: oh i see, i chose paper, clicked submit.. the images displayed are paper vs. rock it says, Draw!

Comment: Then, please check if your 2nd to the last, `else if` is like this `else if($playerthrows == 'paper' && $Computer == 'rock' )`. The one that should echoes `'You Win!`

Comment: sadly it does say that, when i did var_dump it displayed the correct variables assigned edit: when i reload that page it displays the correct output for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see an extensive battery of `if` conditions (or a large repetitive swich-case block), I usually find that the leaner/cleaner solution is to convert the logic to a "look-up" array.  This will make your code more condensed, easier to read, and easier to modify.  This is a page right out of the "Don't Repeat Yourself" manual.

Code: ([Run this Demo to see it at work](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c42e46f9f57d8dae41de0c4628ae395ab9139698))

```
$_POST['playerthrows']='rock';
$humanoutcomes=[
    'paper'=>['paper'=>'Draw','rock'=>'Win','scissors'=>'Lose'],
    'rock'=>['rock'=>'Draw','scissors'=>'Win','paper'=>'Lose'],
    'scissors'=>['scissors'=>'Draw','paper'=>'Win','rock'=>'Lose']
];
if(!isset($_POST['playerthrows']) || !in_array($_POST['playerthrows'],array_keys($humanoutcomes))){
    echo "Ooops, you didn't throw a valid option.  Try again.";
}else{
    $playerthrows=$_POST['playerthrows'];
    $computerthrows=array_rand($humanoutcomes);

    echo "You threw: <img src=\"{$playerthrows}1.png\" alt=\"{$playerthrows}\" />\n";
    echo "Computer threw: <img src=\"{$computerthrows}2.png\" alt=\"{$computerthrows}\" />\n";
    echo "You {$humanoutcomes[$playerthrows][$computerthrows]}";
}
```

Possible Output:

```
You threw: <img src="rock1.png" alt="rock" />
Computer threw: <img src="paper2.png" alt="paper" />
You Lose
```